# htaccess rewrite fake directories to GET parameters in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

My htaccess file is

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ index.php?news=$1 [QSA]
```

so if I goto https://example.com/news/2022-04-01 it should really goto https://example.com?news=2022-04-01 and according to htaccess.madewithlove.com that it what it evaluates to. However, the PHP (index.php in this case), still sees it as /news/2022-04-01 and the $_GET array is empty. Am I missing something really obvious since the whole point of the rewrite is to change it to a GET parameter before it hits my PHP file. Putting this at the start of my PHP file

```
<?php
echo "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]<br/>";
print_r($_GET);
die();
```

shows array() if I pass it as a directory (which shows it does just goto index.php) but array('news'=>'2022-04-01') if I do it as 'normal' parameter passing. So, can it be done in PHP (or JQuery/Javascript).. And if it can be done, please don't hardcode 'news', there are 8 different possibilities being passed so I need a generic routine.
Many thanks
Adrian

Comment: Do you also have a physical directory called "news"?

Comment: Nope, everything will be virtual - it's database driven.

Comment: Just trying to think of a reason for the behaviour you are seeing. In that case, the code you've posted should "work". "the PHP (index.php in this case), still sees it as /news/2022-04-01 and the $_GET array is empty." - Yes, PHP's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is the requested URL, ie. `/news/2022-04-01` - that is "correct". But `$_GET['news']` should contain `2022-04-01` in your example. Try setting `Options -MultiViews` at the top of the file (but that would only be relevant if `news.php` exists, not `index.php`).

Comment: What values are you permitting `/news/<here>`? Your regex is too generic, if you are only accepting "dates" for instance. You should not need the two _conditions_ that perform the filesystem checks, unless a request for `/news/2022-04-01` could possibly map to a file or directory - which seems very unlikely considering you've stated, "Nope, everything will be virtual".

Comment: Playing around, it started working randomly on my development PC running XAMPP but it refuses to on the live web server so I've canned the idea. If people want to look at specific stuff they can just do ?news=xxxx or find it from the home page. But thanks for your answers everyone.

Comment: To clarify, you don't have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Your rule is missing the `L` flag - this is OK if this is all you have in the file, but it will likely fail if you have other directives that follow.